# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php

I have a php bot (on IRC), and since I updated my php and mysql to the last version on CentOS I've come across with this error

```
unset($ops_activos);
    unset($voices_activos);
    if ($on_pthelp == 1) {
        if ($ops["#pthelp"]['count'] > 0) {
            foreach ($ops["#pthelp"] as $value) {
                if (!is_int($value)) {
                    if (isset($ops_activos)) {
                        $ops_activos .= " " . $value;
                    } else {
                        $ops_activos = $value;
                    }
                } 
            }
            if ($bot_debug) {
                scmd("PRIVMSG ". $log_chan ." :[Membros (Mode)] [OPS]: ". $ops_activos);
            }
        }
        unset ($value);
        if ($voices["#pthelp"]['count'] > 0) {
            foreach ($voices["#pthelp"] as $value) {
                if (!is_int($value)) {
                    if (isset($voices_activos)) {
                        $voices_activos .= " " . $value;
                    } else {
                        $voices_activos = $value;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            if ($bot_debug) {
                scmd("PRIVMSG ". $log_chan ." :[Membros (Mode)] [VOICES]: ". $voices_activos);
            }
        }
```

Line with error

```
if ($ops["#pthelp"]['count'] > 0) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the existance of the keys you have in the array before comparing as it can not find it anyway.

use this instead

```
if (isset($ops["#pthelp"]['count']) && $ops["#pthelp"]['count']> 0)
```

also for this will be good to avoid any further problems

```
if (isset($voices["#pthelp"]['count']) &&  $voices["#pthelp"]['count'] > 0)
```

Comment: Hey @KhaledHassan thank you, one more question, at the end of the code i've: unset ($value); $ops_count = ($ops["#pthelp"]['count'] ? $ops["#pthelp"]['count'] : 0); $voices_count = ($voices["#pthelp"]['count'] ? $voices["#pthelp"]['count'] : 0); and got the same error, can you help me?

Comment: Hi @Fdcarvalho , can you please edit your main post in order to understand what is the problem correctly regarding what do you unset and what error cause at which line and so on.